# Apple store question about installing new hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I plan to make a trip up to the apple store tomorrow. I need them to put in a new hard drive in my Macbook Pro mid-2010 15". Do I need to make an appointment with them? or can I just show up and drop it off with them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The generally accepted procedure for any Genius Bar visit is to use the store locator on the Apple site and then use the 'Concierge' web application to book an appointment. While Apple staff (at least in Japan) tend to be rather accommodating for walk-in client issues, having an appointment can ensure your waiting time is minimized. This is especially important at a busier location.

Comment: Yeah, try that on Regent Street in London :P You used to be able to do it, but not any more; appointments only, & count yourself lucky if you can get one within a week.

Comment: Agreed. I had a 4-day wait to get my battery replaced in my iPhone 5.